# Selector of an object inside custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a switch inside a custom cell.  The switch is allocated and set to the accessoryView of the cell inside the .m file of the custom cell.

However, I need the selector method for the switch to be handled in the ViewController of the tableView the custom cell resides in.

Currently when clicking the switch I get a crash that it can't find the selector, most likely because its looking in the cell's .m.

How can I declare my switch to have its selector look in the correct location?

*edit* as per request...

```
//cell .m
- (void)setType:(enum CellType)type
{
    if (_type == SwitchType)
    {
         UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
         [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
         self.accessoryView = switchView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of creating the switch and setting its selector?

Comment: As written, your `flip:` method must be in the cell .m file because you set the switch's target to `self` where `self` appears to be the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy That is pretty much what I suspected, and am essentially asking, what do I set the target to.

Comment: The better solution is to see Shizam's answer. Let the cell handle the switch. Then let the cell notify its delegate that something happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the job for a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html).  Create a protocol in your cell interface like:

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myCell:(MyCell *)sender switchToggled:(BOOL)value;
@end
```

and specify a delegate

```
id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;
```

Then in your MyCell.m, when the switch is toggled check if the delegate is defined, if so call it:

```
if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myCell:switchToggled:)]) {
    [self.delegate myCell:self switchToggled:switch.value]
}
```

And in your ViewController be sure to set the ViewController to be the delegate for the cell and implement the protocol method.

Comment: Since you can send messages to `nil`, there's no need to check if the delegate is not `nil`.

Comment: @Scott still sorta best practice to avoid extra messages.

Comment: Yea and technically since all the methods in the the protocol as I've defined it are required you don't really have to check if it responds to the selector... but it seems like good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your switch as a public property then set its target in `cellForRowAtIndex:`

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *switch;
```

Or you could create a custom `NSNotification` that is fired off. And have your viewController listen for the notification then deal with it.

**Blocktastic :)**

You could also get fancy with blocks.

```
typedef void(^CustomCellSwitchBlock)(BOOL on);

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CustomCellSwitchBlock switchAction;
```

Then in your `CustomCell.m`:

```
- (void)handleSwitch:(UISwitch *)switch
{
    switchAction(switch.on);
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndex:`:

```
cell.action = ^(BOOL on){
    if (on) {
        // Perform On Action
    } else {
        // Perform Off Action
    }
};
```

Comment: is there a way to set the target to the cell's superviews?  until you reach the view controller?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Added another blocktastic option :)